# Why do I get a software not in sources error when installing software?

Tags: 11.10

I am using ubuntu 11.10. I have tried with all options like `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`  I am getting problem for many software while installing in software center, shows error 'not found there isnt software called '------' in your sources.
also this is problem while installing gnome-shell.

```
sanket@sanket-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: gjs (>= 1.29.18) but it is not installable
               Depends: libgjs0c (>= 1.29.18) but it is not installable
               Depends: caribou but it is not installable
               Depends: cups-pk-helper but it is not installable
               Depends: mesa-utils but it is not installable
               Recommends: gnome-themes-standard but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: gnome-session-fallback but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there any problem with Repository ,what should be done????

Answer (score 2):

It might be caused by missing packages in your repository. Try to switch to the main server.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Download_Server

Then re-run update-manager and install any updates.